AWS SFTP server accessible with any SSH key
I have an SFTP server hosted with AWS Transfer Family with a Custom Identity Provider (with authMethod Password OR public key), because it needs to be able to authenticate users by either password or SSH key.
I searched for all possible tutorials and always found code similar to the one I am using in my Lambda function:
user_data = get_user_data(username)
password = event.get("password", '')

if password != '':
    if 'Password' in user_data:
       resp_password = user_data['Password']
    else:
       return {}

    if resp_password != password:
        return {}
else:
    if 'PublicKey' in user_data:
        response['PublicKeys'] = [user_data['PublicKey']]
    else:
        return {}

So if the client doesn't provide a password, we return the persisted PublicKey for that user as PublicKeys: string[].
In my understanding, by doing that, AWS should check if the provided SSH Private Key matches with our returned PublicKey. But the problem now is that, if I try connecting to the SFTP server with sftp -i ANY_KEY user@URL I am able to connect to it no matter what private key I use.
It also has the same behavior if I change the Authentication method to be Public key only.
By checking the logs, the returned response looks like this:
{
    "PublicKeys": [
        "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NRANDOMRANDMRANDOM"
    ],
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/ROLE_NAME",
    "HomeDirectory": "/home/TEST"
}

Add.: In some tutorial it was stated that the response should return a PublicKey: string instead of PublicKeys: string[].

Post sftp -vvv -i ANY_KEY user@URL output. + [mcve] of your Lambda function.
